# Restart tasktracker and job tracker of hadoop CDH4 using Cloudera services

Tags: linux, hadoop, permissions, mapreduce, hdfs

I have made few entries in mapred-site.xml, to pick these changes i need to restart TT and JT running at my cluster nodes.

Is there any i can restart them using Cloud Era manager web services from command line.
So I can automate those steps any time changed made configuration files for hadoop it will restart TT and JT..

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.0, Cloudera Manager exposes its functionality through an HTTP API which allows you to do the operations through "curl" from the shell. The API is available in both the Free Edition and the Enterprise Edition.

Their [repository](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/) hosts a set of client-side utilities for communicating with the Cloudera Manager API. You can find more on the documentation [page](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v3/index.html).